# No 3G but have wifi- have been on phone with apple and provider for 5+ hours total. Ideas?

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 5 that does not take a sim card. It is programmed for StraightTalk which goes through Verizon towers. I've had it over 2 years- finally got the sleep/wake button fixed since that's been a problem and known issue. When I got my phone back, I could no longer access 3G (so no iMessages unless I'm on wifi, no group msgs or photo msgs ever, no web without wifi).

My iOS is up to date. I've called the sat programming repeatedly to update. I took it into a store to check settings. I've been on the phone 4 separate occasions with providers and Apple (who did a remote check through computer and there are no hardware issues- I was told wifi wouldn't work either if there was).  The provider walks me through the same basic steps each time checking dumb things like airplane mode. They always wind up, an hour later, telling me that everything is "fine on their end" and my account is "well provisioned" and it should be getting data. Well, it's not.  Sometimes, they say they'll transfer me to someone else to try to fix it and then they hang up.

This phone doesn't use a sim card, never has, and a card won't work in this type of phone. (I even tested this once with provider and it made nothing work instead of just no 3G.)

I have a friend who had the same issue with the same provider and they said eventually the ST people transferred them to Verizon and they reset something there. So far, I can't get anyone to listen to me to try this, and when I went into Verizon they said it wasn't their problem. The friend didn't have any other specifics as to what the issue was so I can't tell anyone what they did. :/

If anyone out there can help, I'd greatly appreciate it. Seems like a waste to have a smartphone where I can't ever check mail when I'm out (or use browser to look things up or find my way). It's really disheartening to get nowhere after so many hours on the phone with people who don't seem to really know their job other than what the screen prompts them to ask.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you said where you got your phone fixed (I double checked, but I could be missing it), but who fixed it? Was it Apple, a friend, a repair shop? It sounds like something could have been either damaged or disconnected and not reconnected correctly in the repair process.

If you have done a full restore to the device (both from an iCloud/iTunes backup *and* set it up as a new device) then it is probably damaged physically. You need to contact whomever repaired the sleep/wake button.

Comment: Apple itself fixed it and I spent 90 min on the phone with them while they did a remote check. She in the end stated if the hardware was damaged then the wifi would not work either- not just 3G (other people have said the same thing). Everything else checked out fine.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is see if the Straight Talk rep will send you a Verizon nano-SIM.

> This phone doesn't use a sim card, never has, and a card won't work in this type of phone. (I even tested this once with provider and it made nothing work instead of just no 3G.)

The iPhone 5 takes a nano-SIM card. The only to date that never took any SIM card was the CDMA (Verizon) iPhone 4. Additionally, though you can use *3G* with your iPhone 5 without a SIM, you can't use LTE without it and LTE is **much** faster than old 3G.

[image]

Yes, the iPhone in the picture is a 5s (note the gold color) and a GSM one (note the T-Mobile SIM), but as far as the SIM card is concerned, everything's the same there as for a CDMA iPhone 5.

Comment: It's an iphone 5: CDMA model A1429*:  It never has had a SIM card in it (which has confused 3/4 of the people who have checked it for me). I tried last effort to add a SIM card which made nothing work- spent over an hour on the phone with ST and they entered the card data but she transferred me to someone else who said that it cannot work with a sim card (and again, never had one in the 2 working years prior). When added I no longer had ANY service not just no 3G. I am fine using 3G not faster LTE-- if it would work at all. But, it doesn't.

Comment: Weird, does it work at all on any other networks? Next time that you're out, bring your iPhone, go to a Verizon store, and ask the rep if you can test your iPhone for use on Verizon networks. They will take the nano-SIM card out of one of the floor model iPhones and let you put it in your iPhone. If you can access the internet from off of Verizon's network then at least you know that your iPhone itself is fine and that the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: I'll try going to Verizon again- the chick last time seemed clueless. It sucks since I know someone else who went through the same issue (after having the same button fixed by apple!) and had it fixed remotely- but it's been a spirit breaker trying to get a working phone back. And getting hung up on by baffled employees. (Silly me for wanting to be able to power down my phone or take screen shots.) We had put a ST verizon nano SIM in and they go through this (slow) process of registering it- and then they undid it because nothing worked.

Comment: This phone was around shortly before verizon switched something in their towers (I don't remember the technical stuff)- probably as they switched to LTE- I don't know if something there is an issue with not having the old tech specs. I know that sounds uniformed lol...but, until it was reset and sent in to Apple, I had access.   I will go back to verizon and ask around and see if anyone knows anything. ST has been utterly unhelpful.

Comment: I know what you mean, a couple of weeks ago when I set up my old iPhone 5s for my mom to use on Straight Talk the rep told me that it wasn't compatible, after I used the 5s on Straight Talk myself for months. I argued with the rep and told her that I knew that it was compatible on Straight Talk. She started to get angry, so I asked to speak to someone above her, where I was placed on hold for 10 minutes and I just hung up. I called back, got a different rep and we sorted the problem out and had the iPhone activated on ST in 10 minutes. It just depends on who you talk to.